# An exception of type 'System.InvalidCastException' occurred in EntityFramework.Core.dll but was not handled in user code

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework

I am trying to get the `long` value associated to an `ActivityLogType` it is associated to either a `create`, `edit`, and `delete`  record in the database.

It is used for an audit / activity log that is needed.

```
public enum ActivityLogType
{
    Create = 1,
    Update = 2,
    Delete = 3 
}
```

My getter method:

```
public ActivityType GetType(ActivityLogType type)
{
    var id = (long)type;

    Console.WriteLine(id); // <---- this produces a 1 in the console. So the cast works?

    return _context.ActivityTypes.Where(x => x.Id == id).FirstOrDefault(); // <-- This line throws the error 
}
```

**UPDATE 1**

un-lucky suggested using `(long)ActivityLogType.Create` to get the desired output. I tried this: (Still not working)

```
public ActivityType GetType(ActivityLogType type)
{

    switch (type)
    {
        case ActivityLogType.Create:
            return _context.ActivityTypes.Where(x => x.Id == (long)ActivityLogType.Create).FirstOrDefault();
        case ActivityLogType.Update:
            return _context.ActivityTypes.Where(x => x.Id == (long)ActivityLogType.Update).FirstOrDefault();
        case ActivityLogType.Delete:
            return _context.ActivityTypes.Where(x => x.Id == (long)ActivityLogType.Delete).FirstOrDefault();
        default:
        return null;
    }

}
```

UPDATE 2

Here is the `ActivityType` entity

```
public class ActivityType
{

    public ActivityType()
    {
        this.Activities = new HashSet<Activity>();
    }

    [Key, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public long Id { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Label")]
    public string Label { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Display Order")]
    public int Order { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Is Active")]
    public bool IsActive { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Activities")]
    public virtual ICollection<Activity> Activities { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: and what is `ActivityTypes` here

Comment: @un-lucky it is a `DbSet<ActivityType>`

Comment: @un-lucky `public virtual DbSet<ActivityType> ActivityTypes { get; set; }` in my `DbContext.cs`

Comment: Can you please update how the ActivityLogType coded in ActivityType entity and what is the Data Type in DB. The above code working fine for me.

Comment: Instead of using where and firstOrDefault you can just write FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == (long)ActivityLogType.Create).

Comment: @Rijnhardt The updated code also works fine for me. One question here, you are going to store only three values in the ActivityType entity, but you have declared it as long. Is there any specific requirement?

Comment: @SelvaTS I think I found a potential reason why it is not working, I am quickly remigrating the database.

The reason I am storing it as longs is just compatability with the rest of the database. All my other tables are long. (It is an OCD thing -- I understand for performance an int would be better)

Comment: @SelvaTS It is fixed, thanks for the input. There was a mismatch between the db and the entity.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
long id= Int64.Parse(Convert.ChangeType(type, Enum.GetUnderlyingType(type.GetType())).ToString());
```